# Select the parent node from child node

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I have an XML file and need to find the node with a specific description. The code does that and adds it to the xmlFINode. But now I need to select the parent element  of that node (xmlFiNode).

Example XML

```
<dmodule>
<content>
    <faultIsolation>
        <faultIsolationProcedure applicRefId="Software" id="tree1">
            <fault faultCode=" "/>
            <faultDescr>
                <descr>This nodes description</descr>
            </faultDescr>
        </faultIsolationProcedure>
    </faultIsolation>
</content>
```

Code

```
    xmlFINode = "dmodule/content/faultIsolation/faultIsolationProcedure/faultDescr[descr='" + selectedItem + "']"
    Dim parentNode = xmlFINode ?
```

Comment: The XML posted is incomplete.  What does, 'with a specific description' mean?

Comment: Where is the closing </module> tag for a start?

Comment: What library are you using for handling XML/XPath? Most will return the node object with some property/method to access the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below.

```
//faultIsolation/faultIsolationProcedure[.//descr='This nodes description']
```

[image]

Another option using ancestor.

```
//descr[.='This nodes description']/ancestor::faultIsolationProcedure
```

Comment: Thank you that was great. I found I could just call ParentNode too

Comment: Yes, you can do it in multiple ways. like `/parent` or `/..` but just shared one of the possibilities. Please accept the answer if your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use Xml Linq with a dictionary :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of XElement)) = doc.Descendants("faultIsolationProcedure") _
                                                               .GroupBy(Function(x) CType(x.Descendants("descr").FirstOrDefault(), String), Function(y) y) _
                                                               .ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.ToList)



    End Sub

End Module
```